# does leaving the pizza dough longer to ferment compensate for putting too low amount of yeast?

Tags: dough, pizza, yeast

I don't have measuring cups or anything to measure how much dough:yeast ratio there should be. Is it okay to leave the dough for a longer period of time for lower amount of yeast to compensate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short and general: yes.

There is a dependency between the amount of yeast used and the required leavening time. However as a natural growing process it is not following a linear function but an exponential function to the basis of the Euler constant. But before doing an in-depth mathematical analysis of this problem, I would rather recommend to carefully watch your dough. As soon as it has roughly doubled in size it should be ready to use or to swap it in the fridge. In general long fermentation helps to develop more 'complex' flavours.
I personally use for most of my doughs 2-2.5g of fresh yeast for 1kg of dough, let it rise for 4-5h on room temperature and another 20-44h in the fridge.

Comment: *Very* minor nitpick, but the base number of that exponential can be any number >1.

Comment: @LSchoon: From a pure mathematics point of view this is true, but I guess e has some advantage when it comes to natrual growth like the model used here: https://sfamjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/lam.12314 In fact things get even much more complicated when taking into account that the growth process is not endless (http://www.math.chalmers.se/Stat/Bioinfo/Master/Theses/2007/1.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

just a quick addenda - agreed with first post.
However, even with a little yeast, left long enough the dough can go the other way, where the yeast multiplies sufficiently to eat all the nutrients in the dough and you're left with unrecoverable goo.

that said, one gram of dried yeast for a 500g of flour typical loaf, can happily sit out overnight for a 12 hour ferment to be ready to shape and bake in the morning.
eg

https://youtu.be/kB19bv_tHI4

Up the yeast to the more typical 7g and it would need to go in the fridge if it were to sit for that period.
eg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SM5lZ9TICdk

in that last one - bakewithjack - is a vid of what happens when sourdough ferment goes too far to be recoverable - i'm sorry i couldn't find it quickly